# Web Application hosting with amazon server

Tags: sql, sql-server, amazon-web-services

Myself trying to host a web application in amazon server which takes data from database.I tried to make an instance in amazon rds with master username as root and a password.I have mysql workbench . I don't know how to import my .sql files to amazon rds.While going through the tutorial i am getting confused wih the security group and all.My questions are 
1.do i need to create a security group to do my job,to accesss my application from any ip address?
2.how can i create database with this amazon server in sql workbench/sql query browser.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can either create or add your IP address in default security group to access application to Database.
2. Amazon RDS is just another database maintained by Amazon for you.No much difference in usability, You can connect to it from your MYSQL workbench by providing RDS details and you can star using just as another database.